# Linux Based Small Business File Server - SSD caching

Tags: linux, network-shares, hard-drive-cache

I have small NAS working as file server. In work we (me and 2 colleagues) are using [QGIS](http://qgis.org) with attached large raster files (~1GB TIFFs), 2 or 3 on project. Performance of this solution is poor, so I think about buy something more powerful.

I want buy machine with two 1Gb/s network cards and now I have a question about disks.

Do linux have solution to cache files on other drive/partition (I want use SSD) which are frequently requested/downloaded?

e.g. Client1 open project with attached map1.tif file, this file is send to Client1 and cached in SSD, than when Client2 request file map1.tif it is send from cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of possible solutions here, including:

- [dm-cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dm-cache)
- [bcache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcache)
- [flashcache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flashcache)

I can't specifically recommend one solution over the other, having not used them. It's not particularly hard to set up dm-cache or bcache. [This article](https://www.varnish-software.com/blog/accelerating-your-hdd-dm-cache-or-bcache) shows how to set up dm-cache and bcache. The author ends up sticking with dm-cache.

Note that you may first want to ensure the bottleneck is with your storage system rather than with your network or other configuration.